# creating the ORC format HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

With the below HIVE query I am creating a HIVE table in ORC format, which should have been creating it successfully:

```
create table etl_stats.err_mstr_40sq_orc(audt_id int,err_col_lineage_id int,err_cd int, err_dscr string,cntxt_txt string, src_nm string, src_key string)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '/user/warehouse/hive';
```

The table got created successfully, but to cross check when I used the 
"describe formatted ;", I get below output

```
InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
OutputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I go tthe answer, I was missing "EXTERNAL" in my query. thanks

Comment: But why can't we create ORC format internal HIVE table ? Why this limitation?

Comment: Try without location.